# Is there a limitation to mysqli parameterized queries?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, prepared-statement

I want to be familiar with using mysqli parameterized queries.

Is there a limitation to them? Are they only valid for INSERT commands?

This might be a bit extreme, but I was trying to use it on a create table command.

```
$createTableSQL = "
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ?(
    ? VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL, 
    completed BOOL DEFAULT 0,
    expires INT NOT NULL,  
    PRIMARY KEY (?)
)"; 

$tableName = 'token_tracker';
$primaryKey = 'tokens';     

$query = $this->_tokenDB->prepare($createTableSQL); 
$query->bind_param( 'sss', $tableName, $primaryKey , $primaryKey  ); 
$query->execute();
```

I was getting errors like:

> Uncaught Error: Call to a member function bind_param() on boolean

I did some searching, and it seems to be from query failing, and the mysqli_result object being empty?

Is this the wrong way to use prepared statements?

If I just do a straight query on this, with the variables embedded into the query, it will work.

Comment: Limitation: You can only bind to data, not database, table, or column names. Those identifiers use a completely different quoting mechanism.

Comment: You'll need to manually escape and substitute those values, perhaps using `%s` as a placeholder with conventional tools like [`sprintf`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php). If you're generating those names and there's no possibility of user-data leaking into them then straight-up `"...\`%s\`..."` type query placeholders should work.

Comment: One thing to keep in mind is if you're creating N tables in your database to organize things that's probably a sign you're violating the basic principles behind [database normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization). A good relational structure wouldn't require this kind of dynamic schema expansion.

Comment: No, the tables were static. I just thought it was good practice to use parameters so the query can't be screwed with. But I understand now it really is only applicable to user inputs.

Comment: If the tables are static then the names are static and you wouldn't be using placeholders. I'm honestly not sure why PDO and such don't have placeholder support for identifiers as sometimes that's a big issue, but that's a question the PHP core team can better answer.